# How do I remove panel borders?

Tags: extjs, border, frame

I need to **remove all borders**. I already added `border:false` but it's not working.

Note that I want it to have this blue background so I'm using `frame : true`.

### My code

```
        region: 'north',
        split: true,
        border: false, 
        height: 115,
        layout: 'border',
        items: [ {///Account info
            xtype: 'form',
            region: 'east',
            border: false,
            frame: true,
            //height: 100,
            width: 500, //'49%',//anchor : '50%',
            layout: 'column',

                items: [
                    { columnWidth: .5,
                      border: false, 
                      frame: true, 
                      defaults: { labelStyle: 'font-size:9px' },
                      items: [{
                            xtype: 'displayfield',
                            fieldLabel: 'Customer',
                            value: '<span style="color:blue;font-size:9px">IBM</span>'
                        }, {
                            xtype: 'displayfield',
                            fieldLabel: 'Subscription',
                            value: '<span style="color:blue;font-size:9px">On demand</span>'
                        }, {
                            xtype: 'displayfield',
                            fieldLabel: 'Remaining credits',
                            value: '<span style="color:blue;font-size:9px">23</span>'
                        }]

                    }, {
                        columnWidth: .5, 
                        border: false, 
                        frame: true,
                        margin : '0 0 0 8',
                        defaults: { labelStyle: 'font-size:9px' },
                        items: [{
                            xtype: 'displayfield',
                            fieldLabel: 'Account',
                            value: '<span style="color:blue;font-size:9px">Mike</span>'
                        }, {
                            xtype: 'displayfield',
                            fieldLabel: 'credentials',
                            value: '<span style="color:blue;font-size:9px">User</span>'
                        }]

                    }
```

Comment: Posting the code for the component in question would help diagnose the problem. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your problem is that you have `frame: true` configured. Set it to false and it will remove the blue border.

> false by default to render with plain 1px square borders. true to render with 9 elements, complete with custom rounded corners (also see Ext.Element.boxWrap).

Also, the blue background is nothing to do with the `frame` config option

EDIT: When removing `frame: true` you need to add a config option to style the background color...

`bodyStyle: 'background-color:#dfe8f5;'`

EDIT 2: Like Elgin mentioned in the comments, it's probably better to use a transparent background color to make theme changes easier...

`bodyStyle: 'background-color: transparent;'`

Comment: but when i remove frame;true, inside the panel becmes white!! and i need it to stay blue

Comment: I find even this inelegant but, just better, "bodyStyle: {background: 'transparent'}".

This way, you won't have surprises when you change style.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my solution for ExtJs 4.0.7 column model

```
{
layout: 'column',
border:0,
defaults:{
    columnWidth:0.5
   ,layout:'anchor'
   ,border:0
},
items: [{ 
    // LEFT COLUMN
    defaults:{anchor:'100%'},
    items: [
        new Prg.checkBox({
            fieldLabel: 'Aktif mi?',
            name: 'activeFlag',
            labelWidth: 60,
            checked: (Ext.isEmpty(this.record)?false:this.record.get('activeFlag'))
        }),
        new Prg.idCombo({
            fieldLabel : 'Dil',
            labelWidth: 60,
            emptyText : 'Dili seçiniz...',
            id: 'langId',
            name : 'langId',
            store : this.ds_language
        })]
}
```

Here is **layout:column** model is used to make shape of form readable. There was borders on the each column. After long time searching **border:0** works for me.

Answer (score 4):

For ExtJS 3.x remove "frame: true" and set "bodyCssClass: 'x-panel-mc'".

Comment: also set the background color to your choice:     bodyStyle: 'background-color:COLOR;'

Comment: also set the background color to your choice:bodyStyle: 'background-color:COLOR;'

Answer (score 0):

Remove `frame : true` option or put `frame : false` there.

Comment: but i want the frame, i want the blue theme, if i put frame:false it becomes white!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might have this issue I solved it by adding the following to my panel.  (ExtJS 4.x)

```
bodyCls: 'x-panel-body-default-framed'
```

As mentioned above, if you have frame:true you get the rounded corners.